# Difference between Reference Types and References

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I am reading following blog by Eric Lippert: [The truth about Value types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

In this, he mentions there are 3 kinds of values in the opening:

1. Instance of Value types
2. Instance of Reference types
3. References

   > It is incomplete. What about references? References are neither value types nor instances of reference types, but they are values..

So, in the following example:

```
int i = 10;
string s = "Hello"
```

First is instance of value type and second is instance of reference type. So, what is the third type, References and how do we obtain that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what is the third type, References and how do we obtain that?

The variable `s` is a variable which holds the value of the reference.  This value is a reference to a string (with a value of `"Hello"`) in memory.

To make this more clear, say you have:

```
 string s1 = "Hello";
 string s2 = s1;
```

In this case, `s1` and `s2` are both variables that are each a reference to the same reference type instance (the string).  There is only a single actual string instance (the reference type) involved here, but there are two references to that instance.

Answer (score 3):

Fields and variables of reference type, such as your `s`, are references to an instance of a reference type that lives on the heap.

You never use an instance of a reference type directly; instead, you use it through a reference.

Comment: @MarcGravell, "It is simply false that the choice of whether to use the stack or the heap has anything fundamentally to do with the type of the thing being stored" - From Eric Lippert's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

Comment: `s` is a *variable*, not a reference as per the link: "References are neither value types nor instances of reference types, but they are *values*."

Comment: @NewHire and yet that is where they universally are. So while it is not a necessity from the language specification, it remains factually accurate.

Comment: @user indeed, it would be more proper to say "the *value* of `s`"

Comment: @MarcGravell, I can't undo my downvote, how to do that

Comment: @NewHire me neither (or at least, without very good reason). I suspect Schabse will survive a downvote, though :)

Comment: @NewHire: In theory the CLR could allocate the *referent* of a reference type on the stack but in practice this never happens. However a **reference** might be allocated on the stack or the heap, depending on the lifetime of the variable that holds the reference. References are data, they have to live somewhere.

Comment: Is it not accurate to simply say that 10 and "Hello" are instances, but i and s are references?

Comment: @stuartd: No; `i` holds a value directly (since `int` is a value type); it is not a reference.

Comment: @SLaks I suspected as much. So my takeaway from this is that for value types, the variable *is* the value, but for reference types, the variable is just a reference. Now I see that it seems obvious from the names, I'd just never made that connection before.

Comment: @SLaks but if `i` isn't a pointer to a memory location containing the value 10, then what is it?

Comment: @stuartd: The value of a variable of value type is an instance of the value type. The value of a variable of reference type is a reference to an instance of the reference type. Clear?

Comment: @stuartd: You have a chest of drawers. One drawer contains a wrench. That drawer has a label on it that says "MY WRENCH DRAWER". It is the 12th drawer from the top in your chest of drawers. Which of the following things are **the same thing**: (1) the drawer, (2) the label, (3) the number 12, (4) the wrench ? The variable is not its address any more than a drawer is either its label or its position.

Comment: @EricLippert now I a) finally understand and b) feel slightly foolish for not understanding before, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A reference is not really a 'third type'. It's actually a pointer that refers to a concrete instance of an object. Take a look at this example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Str { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        var myObj = new MyClass
        {
            Str = "Whatever"
        };

        Console.WriteLine("{0};\t{1};\t{2};\t{3}", a, b, c, myObj.Str);
        MyFunction(a, ref b, out c, myObj);
        Console.WriteLine("{0};\t{1};\t{2};\t{3}", a, b, c, myObj.Str);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void MyFunction(int justValue, ref int refInt, out int outInt, MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.Str = "Hello";
        justValue = 101;
        refInt = 102;
        outInt = 103; // similar to refInt, but you MUST set the value of the parameter if it's uses 'out' keyword
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
1;      2;      3;      Whatever
1;      102;    103;    Hello
```

Focus on the MyFunction:

The first parameter we pass is a simple int which is a value type. By default value types are cloned when passed as the parameter (a new instance is being created). That's why the value of 'a' didn't change.

You can change this behavior by adding 'ref' or 'out' keyword to the parameter. In this case you actually pass a reference to that very instance of your int. In MyFunction the value of that instance is being overridden.
[Here you can read move out ref and out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

The last example is the object of MyClass. All classes are reference types and that's why you always pass them as references (no special keywords needed).

You can think about a reference as about an address in computer memory. Bytes at that address compose your object. If you pass it as value, you take that bytes out and pass them to a function. If you pass it as a reference you only pass the address. Than in your called function you can read bytes from that address or write to that address. Every change affects the calling function variables, because they point to exactly the same bytes in computer memory. **It's not exactly what happens in .Net (it runs in a virtual machine)**, but I think this analogy will help you understand the concept.

Why do we use references? There are many reasons. One of them is that passing a big object by value would be very slow and would require cloning it. When you pass a reference to an object, than no matter how big that object is you only pass w few bytes that contain it's 'address' in memory.

Moreover your object may contain elements that cannot be cloned (like an open socket). Using reference you can easily pass such an object between functions.

It's also worth mentioning that sctructs, even though they look very similar to classes are actually value types and behave as value types (when you pass a struct to a function, you actually pass a clone - a new instance).